# How to force PHP to output a number preceded by zeros?

Tags: php

```
for ($number = 1; $number <= 16; $number++) {
    echo $number . "\n";
}
```

This code outputs:

```
1
2
3
...
16
```

How can I get PHP to output the numbers preceded by zeros?

```
01
02
03
...
16
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) to format your number to a string, or [`printf`](http://php.net/printf) to format it and display the string immediatly.

You'd have to specify a format such as this one, I'd say : `%02d` :

- padding specifier = `0`
- width specifier = `2`
- integer = `d`

*(Even if you have what you want here, you should read the manual page of `sprintf` : there are a lot of possibilities, depending on the kind of data you are using, and the kind of output formating you want)*

And, as a demo, if `temp.php` contains this portion of code :

```
<?php
for ($number = 1; $number <= 16; $number++) {
    printf("%02d\n", $number);
}
```

Calling it will give you :

```
C:\dev\tests\temp>php temp.php
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [**str_pad().**](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php)

> **str_pad — Pad a string to a certain length with another string**
>
> This functions returns the input string padded on the left, the right, or both sides to the specified padding length. If the optional argument pad_string  is not supplied, the input  is padded with spaces, otherwise it is padded with characters from pad_string  up to the limit.

Answer (score 4):

The old-fashioned way: 
`$str = sprintf("%02.2d", $number);`
or use 
`printf("%02.2d\n", $number);`
to print it immediately.

Answer (score 3):

```
for ($number = 1; $number <= 16; $number++) {
  echo sprintf("%02d", $number) . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`if($number < 10) echo '0' . $number;`

I know there are a lot better answers than this here, but I though't I'd leave it to show there's more than one way to skin a cat...

Comment: This needs an else branch. Otherwise numbers > 10 aren't printed at all.

Comment: I know. I assumed that Andrew would be able to work out the rest... It's just meant to be a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Quick method:

```
<?php
for ($number = 1; $number <= 16; $number++)
{    
    if($number < 10)
        echo "0".$number."\n";
    else
        echo $number."\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here, I don't think efficiency is OP's highest worry. But hey it was just a simple answer for a simple question. Sorry your nose is too high up in the clouds at this point though!

Answer (score 0):

Lets keep it simple.
Use str_pad

echo str_pad(1, 6 , "0");

produces 000006

Answer (score 0):

echo ($number < 10) ? (0 . $number) : $number;

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
  for ($number = 1; $number <= 16; $number++) 
  { 
    if($number<10)
      echo '0';
    echo $number . "<br>"; 
  }
?>
```

Comment: That would give you 010, 011, 012, etc.

Comment: please use ctrl+k to mark code blocks (or indent the code manually with 4 spaces)

Comment: you see how the printf approach is superior, I hope?

Comment: absolutely, much cleaner code! I didn't know about str_pad(), which seems really handy.